# What's the meaning of "jiggelty-jolt"?

Tags: word-meaning

> ONCE on a time there was a boy named Jack, and one morning he started
>   to go and seek his fortune.
>
> He hadn't gone very far before he met a cat.
>
> 'Where are you going, Jack?' said the cat.
>
> 'I am going to seek my fortune.'
>
> 'May I go with you?'
>
> 'Yes,' said Jack, 'the more the merrier.'
>
> So on they went, **jiggelty-jolt, jiggelty-jolt**.

This content is from "How Jack went to Seek his Fortune" in English fairly tales.

Could you teach me the meaning of "jiggelty-jolt"?

Comment: It's just an alliterative form more familiar as ***jiggity jig*** (particularly in the nursery rhyme [*To market, to market, to buy a fat pig, Home again, home again, **jiggety-jig.**)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/To_market,_to_market). Similar to ***clippety-clop*** for horses. If you want a more precise definition of what it "means" in your exact context, perhaps ***with a lively step***.

Comment: I don't know how to answer that. Take, for example [*There goes a rabbit, hippity-hop!*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=rabbit+%22hippity+hop%22). In some sense it obviously "means" something - if nothing else, we can at least be sure the rabbit was moving quite quickly. But it's more a matter of saying such alliterative forms have *connotations*, once you've gone beyond the basic "attempt to **represent the sound** of an animal or person moving quickly with a lively step".